# How often do plants, resources, diamonds, and other procurement items respawn?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I can't tell if the items that I've been finding out in the wilderness have been respawning or if I'm imagining things.  I've been finding a lot of diamonds, fuel, plants, and the like and some of them have their location marked on my map with a number.  Does that mean that I can only pick them up once?

What items respawn and how often?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources re-spawn every three main missions you do.

This also includes all the rough diamonds around Mother Base so you can harvest all of them again. A little grind but lots of GMP.

Comment: Does it counts repeat completed missions or I need to progress main missions?

Comment: @IvanSolntsev: I am pretty sure that it does count missions to be whatever mission you do -- so side ops count as missions.  If you spend ages free roaming, then nothing will change much.

Comment: I meant repeating already completed main missions.

Comment: @IvanSolntsev: yes, repeating a main mission counts as playing a mission.